# Code Sharing between WPF Windows,WindowsPhone and Windows Store Applications

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

We have planned to develop an application for the platforms 
    WPF Desktop,
    Windows Phone and
    Windows store.I want to share C# code and Xaml design between these platforms.I know that it is not possible to share the whole set of codes.Experts please guide me.Which frame work(MVC,MVVM,etc.)I have to develop?And how much possibilities are there for sharing?

Comment: **Your question is Too broad for Stackoverflow.** Modularize as much as you can. There might be specific parts of XAML where you will have issues. Otherwise begin coding for WinRT XAML (which is a subset of WPF XAML), that way you will reduce the amount of rework needed. XAML is suited for MVVM, not MVC.

Comment: Have you tried **searching** before posting here? There are tons of resources to be found by just typing the title of your post in the search?

Comment: one of them : [MSDN : Maximize code reuse between Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681693%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: I was expecting Some useful links explaining the scenarios that to be followed while developing,Anyway thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your c# business logic code use the Portable Class Library project in Visual Studio 2012 it supports the cross-platform development of .NET Framework apps. You can build portable assemblies that work on multiple platforms (Windows 7, Windows 8, Silverlight, Windows Phone, Xbox 360).